# Quick fix for org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:467)

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, stack-overflow

I've encountered the following problem with both Axis2 v1.6.1 and v1.6.2, when using lists:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: 
org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:467) 
org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:467)
org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:467)
...
```

I did a deep search on this and realized that this issue won't be fixed until Apache releases Axis2 v1.6.2. 
Does anyone have a quick fix for that?
Thanks!

Comment: We appreciate your work and contribution to the community, however this is strictly a Q&A site. Voting to close and delete afterwards.

Comment: It does seem a bit silly though doesn't it - if Maayan pretended to ask a question and then answered it it would be fine.

Comment: @Hound Dog You are totally right! See this [question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78837/etiquette-how-do-i-insert-some-useful-info-into-the-form-of-a-question). Maayan, please change your useful info into a Q&A format to avoid deletion.

Comment: Of course, it's a Q&A site. I use it myself a lot of times when I'm stuck with a problem. You may take it as "My Question" and then "My Answer". it took me 2 days to find the resolution and verify it, and I thought that other developers will appreciate saving them a couple of frustrating days. I'll change it to the requested format, just because I love you all :)

Comment: had to wait for 8 hours (which took it to the next day...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in **axis2-adb-1.6.1.jar** file.
If you cannot wait for 1.6.2 to be released, I've created a new jar, **based on v1.6.1**, which fixes this problem; the code I used is based on Apache's source code (their trunk), and the bugfix is similar to the fix they did for 1.6.2 (Thanks, Sagara Gunathunga :)). I didn't change anything except from this specific bugfix.

You can download the jar from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3543130/axis2-adb-1.6.1.bugfix-5195.jar), don't forget to remove the old axis2-adb-1.6.1.jar when you copy this jar into your lib directory.

Once you did that (and restart your application, of course) - the problem is gone.

I'll try to keep this jar on my dropbox as long as v1.6.2 is not released.

Hope all of you java developers will find it useful soon when upgrading to Axis2 1.6.1.